# Removing non alpha characters

Tags: c#

What is the best way in order to remove all non-alpha characters in C#? I have looked up Regex but it doesn't seem to recognise Regex when I do:

```
string cleanString = "";
    string dirtyString = "I don't_8 really know what ! 6 non alpha- is?";
        cleanString = Regex.Replace(dirtyString, "[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");
```

Regex comes with a red wiggly line underneath. Is there a way I can remove simply non alpha letters and if so can some provide me with a sample? I'm not sure if loops and arrays are the way to go and also how can I get all non alpha characters? I'm assuming I have to do something like if doesn't equal A-Z or 0-9, then remove with ""?

Comment: As for the *red wiggly line* did you add `using System.Text.RegularExpressions`?

Comment: Code produces "Idont8reallyknowwhat6nonalphais" (which feels to be your goal). Maybe you have some compile error?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker No I didn't, never used Regex before so did't know I needed that. Thank you. I can see it as how Alexi got it. Now I need to change it so I can keep the space and remove numbers and non alpha characters.

Comment: cleanString = Regex.Replace(dirtyString, "[^a-zA-Z ' ']",""); Got it! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do it using LINQ like so:

```
var cleanString = new string(dirtyString.Where(Char.IsLetter).ToArray());
```

You can check other Char checks on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char_methods(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

> Regex comes with a red wiggly line underneath.

Then either:

1. The compilation prediction isn't working correctly (it does sometimes get things wrong).
2. You don't have a `using System.Text.RegularExpressions` in the code, so it can't work out you mean `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` when you say `Regex`.

To return to your original question:

> What is the best way in order to remove all non-alpha characters in C#?

The approach you take is good for small strings, though `[^A-Za-z0-9]` will remove non-alphanumerics and `[^A-Za-z]` non-alphabetical characters. This is assuming you are already restricted to (or want to add a restriction to) US-ASCII characters. To include letters like `á`, `œ`, `ß` or `δ` because you're dealing with real words rather than computer-code I'd use `@"\P{L}"` or `@"[^\p{L}\p{N}]"` to allow all letters and numbers.

If you are dealing with very large piece of text (many kilobytes) then you are better off reading it through a filtering stream that strips the characters you don't want as you go.